# list of dictionaries from kwargs of key:set pair

Tags: python

```
def funct ( **kwargs ):
   #code goes here
```

I have variable number of arguments being passed to this function. the arguments are of the form key1 : {set1}, key2 : {set2}, and so on

Inside the funct I want to have the following data structure some how "synthesized" from the given kwargs

if the function is called like
funct ( key1 = {1,2,3}, key2 = {4,5} )
 params were passed I want the following

```
[    
{ key1 : 1, key2 : 4 },
{ key1 : 2, key2 : 4},
{ key1 : 3, key2 : 4},
{ key1 : 1, key2 : 5 },
{ key1 : 2, key2 : 5},
{ key1 : 3, key2 : 5}
]
```

should work the same way if funct was passed arbitrary number of key : set pairs.

How can I accomplish this. The simpler the solution the better.

using python 3.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is a convenient way to go about this.

```
import itertools


def dict_product(**kwargs):
    """
    Cartesian product of kwargs as dicts with the same keys.

    >>> p = list(dict_product(key1=[1, 2, 3], key2=[4, 5]))
    >>> p.sort(key=lambda d: d['key1'])
    >>> p == [
    ...     {'key1': 1, 'key2': 4},
    ...     {'key1': 1, 'key2': 5},
    ...     {'key1': 2, 'key2': 4},
    ...     {'key1': 2, 'key2': 5},
    ...     {'key1': 3, 'key2': 4},
    ...     {'key1': 3, 'key2': 5},
    ... ]
    True
    """
    items = kwargs.items()
    keys = [key for key, value in items]
    sets = [value for key, value in items]

    for values in itertools.product(*sets):
        yield dict(zip(keys, values))
```